# How to change the UTC time in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, timezone

How to change my UTC time as similar to my local time? The local time and RTC time displays the correct time, but UTC time is wrong and my DB and code chooses the UTC time. So how to change the Universal Time?

timedatectl:

```
       Local time: Tue 2021-06-08 00:33:24 IST
   Universal time: Mon 2021-06-07 19:03:24 UTC
         RTC time: Tue 2021-06-08 00:33:24
        Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
```

Comment: unless I'm missing something here - you can't change UTC, it's the same time throughout the world. Universal Time Coordinated as used by the aviation and marine sectors military etc.

Comment: UTC time is *standard* time set by world clocks (the same anywhere in the world, zulu/GMT/etc are all UTC), having it *adjustable* or *controllable* by a user (and not pre-defined) makes no sense at all.

Comment: You didn't post the complete output of `timedatectl`, but assuming that your UTC time is correct (= your clock is synchronized), instead of trying to change the UTC (which is not possible) you should change the **settings** of your "DB" (whatever that is) to use your "local time". So your question should be: ***How do I change my DB (or its front end) settings to use local time, instead of UTC?***

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want, but it keeps my Windows and Ubuntu times in sync: https://www.howtogeek.com/323390/how-to-fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting/

Answer (score 2):

You can set your date and time by opening Settings → *Date & Time* → and setting *Automatic Date and Time* to on.

[image: Date & Time]

Also, you could click on *Time Zone*, set in my case to CEST (Paris), where you can change your location from the interactive map using the search tool if necessary.

[image: Time Zone setting]

Once these settings are adjusted, the time stamps on program files (such as Databases, if that is what you mean by DB) and elsewhere should be correct.